# Python 3 - Use an existing HEX string and write the HEX as raw data

Tags: python, string, hex

Example (using XVI32.exe (HEX editor)):

ASCII file includes `0001FF30`

Expected result (spaces added only for the example):

> ```
> HEX - 00 01 FF 30 
> DEC - 0 1 255 48
> ```

Existing methods are not bit for bit accurate

```
# Write HEX as characters using bytearray
infile = open('input.txt', 'r')
infiledata = infile.read().strip()
infile.close()
outfile = open('output.txt', 'w')
outfile.write(bytearray.fromhex(infiledata).decode('latin1'))
outfile.close()

# Write HEX as characters using binascii
import binascii
infile = open('input.txt', 'r')
infiledata = infile.read().strip()
infile.close()
outfile = open('output.txt', 'w')
outfile.write(binascii.unhexlify(infiledata).decode('latin1'))
outfile.close()
```

Is there a way to write HEX directly to the file maintaining bit for bit accuracy (RAW Data)? The function works using an external application XVI32.exe when using the paste from HEX string function. I just wanted to do this in Python to save a step.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are unsatisfied with the content of the `output.txt`? Running your first example gives me `0001 ff30` as content

Comment: Using 0001FF30 as the input file the output file in a hex editor is 0001C3BF30  May I ask how you received the correct value?

Comment: I simply ran the first half of your example code, the one with the comment `# Write HEX as characters using bytearray`. This is not the case for you?

Comment: I have a feeling the file needs to be converted for Windows

Comment: Just staying in Linux : Input file is 0001FF30 which is correct but the output file is 5 bytes.  The Hex value is 00 01 C3 BF 30 in a HEX editor.  The conversion in HEX should be 00 01 FF 30:  I'm not worried what the characters read but I'm trying to write the raw data as the HEX value of my choice.

Answer (score 2):

To write the hexdump in binary, you need to drop the Latin-1 encoding (encoding means *not* *raw*), and write the raw byte array instead (using the "b" mode in `open`):

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    hexdump = f.read().strip()
with open("output.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytearray.fromhex(hexdump))
```

For your example input `"0001FF30"`, this gives a 4 byte file.

Comment: Due to this redundant decoding, the character `0xFF` gets UTF8 encoded into two bytes `C3 BF`, which is the underlying reason.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was the decode language but couldn't figure out the work around.  Thanks again!  While goofing around I modified the input file, ran a Linux command echo -n -e "$(cat input.txt)" > outfile.txt which worked as well, but preferred using Python with the generated HEX file.